# Is it possible to change service's plan on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

For example I started user [SQL Database](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/sql-database/) service with a free plan and later decided to upgrade it to a small plan, is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is support for changing a service instances plan starting with CloudFoundry v192 (Bluemix is at v210 as of this post).  However, a service must explicitly provide support for an update action and not all services do this.  When the update support is available for a service, you should expect to be able to perform an upgrade via the `cf update-service` command or via the service's dashboard in the UI.

You used SQL DB as an example and it does not currently provide update support.  If you attempt to perform an upgrade, you should see a message indicating that support is not provided

```
$ cf update-service mysqldb_service -p sqldb_small
Updating service instance mysqldb_service as jimmcvea@us.ibm.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 110004, message: The service does not support changing plans.
```

CloudFoundry documentation about service plan updating can be found at:
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html#update_service

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they want you to use the free plan to get you going and feel comfortable with the environment.

When you add a service, you can choose the plan (eg. free Beta, Small, Premium).  You should keep all your DDL/data handy when you are ready to build the new database.

On this link 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/sql-database/
On the right side, it has an "Add Service" and "Plan" section on the right hand side.  You can toggle the dropdown from "Free Beta" to Small / Premium.

Comment: I didn't find a way how to do it. Can you please provide a short guide how to change plan?

Comment: Your solution works find when I create a **new service**, but how do I change a plan on **existing one** service?

Comment: As @jimmc mentions, this is a current restriction.  You'll have to recreate the db with a new added service.